# Rigid body objects passing through each other

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I am experimenting with rigid body physics using the game engine for a project.

This is the setup:

- I have 2 long rectangular prisms with hole.
- The 2 prisms are connected with a cylinder (acting as a dowel).
- I locked translation and rotation for one of the prism and everything else is free to move and/or rotate.

And here's the problem:

The dowel and the free prism are going through the locked prism. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Here is the blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o2y0pxk7ijk12bc/untitled.blend

Comment: @CoDEmanX Thank you. I should have done that in the very beginning :)

Comment: I think its something about the Collision bounds, the rectangular prisms are actually convex, which is not suitable to be set as **Box**.

Comment: @LeonCheung That didn't work. I changed the prisms to convex hull and experimented with the margins but neither solved the issue. The dowel and prism still go through the other prism.

Comment: @LeonCheung There isn't a concave setting. All I have is capsule, box, sphere, cylinder, cone, convex hull and triangular mesh.

Comment: Sorry for typo, I mean they are CONCAVE. :P You may consider using the compound in Collision setting. Or try **Triangle Mesh**. And be sure to apply their scale.

Comment: I tried everything in collision bounds and nothing worked. same for compound.

Comment: I noticed their scale has't been applied yet. Select them, Ctrl-A > Scale (or Rot/Scale).

Comment: Just applied scale. Still the same. Is rigid body the right physics type for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several problems in this file:

1. Objects scale hasn't been applied;
2. Setting **Triangle Mesh** here is required, since the prisms have holes, which means they are concave objects, so other collision types don't work well with them;
3. Bound margin should be tweaked carefully, as well. Considering the distance between the surface, try smaller value;
4. The two prisms stay too close to each other, which will cause "intersection" if bound margin is non-zero.

   [Demo file_v3](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26723). Just FYI.

---

Added a [demo video](http://youtu.be/jlvmElEmHH4) for better understanding.

Comment: That was magic. So the above 4 points you pointed out were the only problems? Or was there other issues?

Comment: Basically true. However, as you see in the demo file, I locked some rotation and translation axis for a better result. That's the other nice thing to do in your case, but that's not the key here.

Comment: Ridgid Body simulation has a lot of issues with concave shapes. Sergey Reich works on a special "concave" type, but no schedule unfortunately.